# SQL query - Contracts that were not renewed

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have Contracts table with the following fields:

- ContractID - key of the table
- ContractNum - can appear multiple times in case the contract was - renewed
- StartDate
- EndDate
- RenualReminderDays

If a contract is renewed - I generate new record with new ContractID and the same ContractNum.

I want to return the record that: Diff between today and EndDate <= RenualReminderDays
and that for each one there is no record in Contracts with the same ContractNum and with StartDate>EndDate (I mean it was not renewed).

How can I do it in access without using Not In?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something along the lines of the following:

```
select * from contracts c1
where 
    c1.enddate - date() <= c1.renualreminderdays and 
    not exists 
    (
        select 1 from contracts c2 
        where c2.contractnum = c1.contractnum and c2.startdate > c1.enddate
    )
```

You could alternatively use a `left join` in the following way:

```
select c1.* 
from
    contracts c1 left join contracts c2 on 
    c1.contractnum = c2.contractnum and 
    c1.enddate < c2.startdate
where 
    c1.enddate - date() <= c1.renualreminderdays and
    c2.contractid is null
```

Note that MS Access cannot represent unequal join criteria in Design View, but the above SQL is still valid and can be executed by the JET database engine.

Comment: Thank you. You solved my problem. Is it better to use left join instead of "not exists" in Access for better performance)?

Comment: @user3340983 You're most welcome. Without testing, I'm unsure of which method offers better performance as the database engine may optimise the query; I would suspect the join would be faster than a correlated subquery. If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark the answer as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate), so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unsure how to do this. Thanks!